# How to manage imports in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java project with its own sh file for compiling and running. When I try to open the project in Eclipse, I run into problems. Here's the navigator view in Eclipse:

[image]

The problems exist in Indexer.java:

[image]

These pdfbox files exist in a folder that can be seen on the first printscreen. As you can see, its contents cannot be used by Eclipse, and I get an import error. So how do I fix this? If I compile with my `.sh` file in the terminal, I don't get any problems. The `.sh` file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! [ -d classes ];
then
mkdir classes
fi
javac -cp pdfbox -d classes ir/Engine.java ir/Tokenizer.java ir/TokenTest.java ir/Index.java ir/Indexer.java ir/Searcher.java ir/HashedIndex.java ir/PersistentHashedIndex.java ir/Query.java ir/QueryType.java ir/RankingType.java ir/PostingsList.java ir/PostingsEntry.java ir/SearchGUI.java pagerank/PageRankReader.java ir/SpellingOptionsDialog.java
```

So, how can I make this work in eclipse? I don't want to code in the terminal, since it's such a hassle to do things like JUnit testing, viewing different files, etc.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-source-attachment.htm)?

Comment: Yes, it's not helping me. None of the three bullet points work are possible to do for me. The bullets in order...: 1: I can't find the context or project menu. I find no information online of where it is. 2: No such thing as a *library's node* in the java build page menu. 3: There is no Attach source button to be found. Seems like this guide is written for another version or that it's dated.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Oxygen. I found the same page for it, but it looks the same, so same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Class Folder -> Select your folder(pdfbox) -> Clean and Build your projcet(may automically)